Unable to store JWT Token
I am in the process of learning to build an app using Vue3+Vite, and Pinia, with PHP as the backend and MySQL as the database engine. I have created a login form that authenticates against the users table and, upon success, stores the token in LocalStorage. Although I can log in successfully, when I refresh the browser, the app prompts me to log in again, i am thinking that the token was not saved to localStorage.
Maybe some folks here can guide me.
Here are my codes:
App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header 
      @toggle-sidebar="toggleSidebar" 
      @openLogin="showLoginModal = true" 
      @showSuccess="handleShowSuccess"
      @showError="handleShowError"
      @openChangePassword="showChangePasswordModal = true"
    />

    <div class="d-flex" style="margin-top: 56px;">
      <transition name="sidebar">
        <Sidebar v-if="isSidebarVisible" />
      </transition>
      <div
        class="flex-grow-1 p-3"
        :style="{ marginLeft: isSidebarVisible ? '200px' : '0', transition: 'margin-left 0.3s ease' }"
      >
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
    <LoginModal 
      v-if="showLoginModal" 
      @close="showLoginModal = false" 
      @openRegister="showRegistrationModal = true" 
      @showSuccess="handleShowSuccess"
      @showError="handleShowError"
    />
    <RegistrationModal 
      v-if="showRegistrationModal" 
      @close="showRegistrationModal = false" 
      @openLogin="showLoginModal = true"
      @showSuccess="handleShowSuccess"
      @showError="handleShowError"
    />
    <ChangePasswordModal 
      v-if="showChangePasswordModal" 
      @close="showChangePasswordModal = false"
      @showSuccess="handleShowSuccess"
      @showError="handleShowError"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue';
import LoginModal from './components/LoginModal.vue';
import RegistrationModal from './components/RegistrationModal.vue';
import ChangePasswordModal from './components/ChangePasswordModal.vue'; 
import { useUserStore } from './stores/userStore';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Sidebar,
    LoginModal,
    RegistrationModal,
    ChangePasswordModal,
  },
  setup() {
    const isSidebarVisible = ref(true);
    const showLoginModal = ref(false);
    const showRegistrationModal = ref(false);
    const showChangePasswordModal = ref(false);
    const userStore = useUserStore();

    // Get the global properties instance
    const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance();

    const handleShowSuccess = (config) => {
      // Access SweetAlert2 via globalProperties
      proxy.$swal.fire(config);
    };

    const handleShowError = (config) => {
      // Access SweetAlert2 via globalProperties
      proxy.$swal.fire(config);
    };

    watch(
      () => userStore.isAuthenticated,
      (newVal) => {
        if (!newVal) {
          showLoginModal.value = true;
        } else {
          showLoginModal.value = false;
          showRegistrationModal.value = false;
          showChangePasswordModal.value = false;
        }
      }
    );

    const toggleSidebar = () => {
      isSidebarVisible.value = !isSidebarVisible.value;
    };

 
    onMounted(() => {
      userStore.initializeStore();
      if (!userStore.isAuthenticated) {
        showLoginModal.value = true;
      }
    });     

    return {
      isSidebarVisible,
      showLoginModal,
      showRegistrationModal,
      showChangePasswordModal,
      toggleSidebar,
      handleShowSuccess,
      handleShowError,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
/* Transition for sidebar */
.sidebar-enter-active,
.sidebar-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.sidebar-enter-from {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.sidebar-enter-to {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/* Optional: Adjust main content transition */
.flex-grow-1 {
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease;
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px; /* Ensure body content starts below the fixed header */
}
</style>

userStore.js
// src/stores/userStore.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({
    user: {}, // Initialize user as an empty object
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '', // Retrieve token from localStorage
  }),
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated: (state) => !!state.token,
  },
  actions: {
    initializeStore() {
      const storedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');

      if (this.token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`;
      }

      // Safely parse user data if it exists
      if (storedUser) {
        try {
          this.user = JSON.parse(storedUser);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing user data:', error);
          this.logout(); // Logout if user data is invalid
        }
      }
    },
    async login(username, password) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/login.php', {
          username,
          password,
        });

        // Store token and user data after login
        this.token = response.data.token;
        this.user = response.data.user;

        localStorage.setItem('token', this.token); // Store the token in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user)); // Store user data in localStorage

        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error);
        throw error;
      }
    },
    async register(userData) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/register.php', userData);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    },
    async changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/change_password.php', {
          old_password: oldPassword,
          new_password: newPassword,
        });
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    },
    logout() {
      this.token = '';
      this.user = {};
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      localStorage.removeItem('user'); // Clear user data from localStorage
      delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    },
  },
});

LoginModal.vue
<!-- src/components/LoginModal.vue -->
<template>
  <div
    class="modal fade show d-block"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
    style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="username"
                v-model="username"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                class="form-control"
                id="password"
                v-model="password"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useUserStore } from '../stores/userStore';

export default {
  name: 'LoginModal',
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const username = ref('');
    const password = ref('');
    const userStore = useUserStore();

    const handleLogin = async () => {
      try {
        await userStore.login(username.value, password.value);
        emit('close');
        // Access SweetAlert2 via globalProperties
        emit('showSuccess', {
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Logged In',
          text: 'You have successfully logged in!',
          confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        });
        
        // Clear the input fields after successful login
        username.value = '';
        password.value = '';
      } catch (error) {
        emit('showError', {
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Login Failed',
          text: 'Please check your username and password.',
          confirmButtonText: 'Retry',
        });
      }
    };

    const openRegister = () => {
      emit('close');
      emit('openRegister');
    };

    return {
      username,
      password,
      handleLogin,
      openRegister,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.modal {
  display: block;
}

.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1.75rem auto;
}

.modal.fade .modal-content {
  animation-name: modalFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes modalFadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
</style>


I have found the answer.
The problem lies that the new version of firebase/php-jwt requires three arguments for the JWT::encode() method, while i am just putting two arguments there, therefor the token was not returned properly.
Originial JWT::encode
return JWT::encode($payload, self::$secret_key);

Update JWT::encode
return JWT::encode($payload, self::$secret_key, 'HS256');

Thank you for you time
